# Is kernel mode the time when OS gains full control of the system?

Tags: operating-system, kernel

I find that computer system is utilizing in dual-mode way, which comprises kernel and user mode. I wonder if kernel mode and the time OS achieves full control of the computer system are equivalent or not.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  One core may be in kernel mode and the others executing user code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is kernel mode the time when OS gains full control of the system?

That's not a good way of looking at things. Processors generally have multiple modes of operation (usually 2 or 4 but sometimes others) that have different levels of privilege. One of those modes is Kernel mode.

So kernel mode is the the time when the processor is executing at the highest privilege level.

The operating system may not have full control when executing in kernel mode. It is possible on some systems for application code to run in kernel mode IF the process or application has sufficient privilege.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you check Chapter 1.4.2 Dual-mode and Multimode operation from the famous Dinosaur book: Operating System Concepts,10th by Abraham Silberschatz.

CPUs from the different vendor have different implementation of kernel mode. for example, Intel processors have four different modes, 0 being a kernel mode, 3 being a user mode and ARM v8 has 7 different modes. Also, we have a sperate mode for virtual machine manager, it has more privileges than user mode but fewer than the kernel.

also, your question is not clear to me. hopefully, this will give you a decent start point.